# Unlogical output of C code

Tags: c, pointers, char, nested-if

I wrote some lines of following code.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
    float t,res;
    char c;
    scanf("%f",&t); 
    getchar();
    scanf("%s",&c);
    if (c=='R') res = 4/5 * t;
    else if (c=='F') res = (9/5 * t) + 32;
    else if (c=='K') res = t + 273;
    printf("%.2f",&res);
    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why the output shown 0.00 when I give t = 25 and c = 'R'. The console looks like this.

```
25
R
0.00
```

Would any body give me an explanation?

Comment: `printf()` expects `res`, not `&res`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&c);` --> `scanf(" %c",&c);`

Comment: "when I give t = 25 and c = 'R'" How? If you enter `R` from the standard input, not your debugger, you will invoke *undefined behavior* by accessing out-of-range. `%c` should be used instead of `%s` to read one character.

Comment: Perhaps `c =  getchar();`  needed instead of `scanf("%s",&c);`

Comment: I've just tried your advise, but sorry it still doesn't work

Comment: Integer division: `res = 4/5 * t;` should be `res = 4.0/5.0 * t;` or something similar to force floating point division.  Using floating point constants in what you want to be floating point arithmetic — using integers invites problems.  Also, it's a good idea to end print operations with a newline.

Comment: Do not edit questions using suggestions and fixes posted in the answers, as this makes the entire post incomprehensible for future readers.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  Then the incorrect syntax for the `printf()` parameters would have been caught (and fixed by you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `scanf("%s",&c);` has a big chance to cause out-of-range access, which invokes *undefined behavior*. Use `scanf("%c",&c);` (`%c` instead of `%s`) to read only one character.
- `printf("%.2f",&res);` will invoke *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. Use `printf("%.2f",res);` (without `&`) to print data having type `double` (or `float`, which will automatically converted to `double` in variable-length arguments)
- The expressions `res = 4/5 * t` and `res = (9/5 * t) + 32` may not do what you want because `4/5` and `9/5` are integer divisions, in which remainders are truncated. Try using `res = 4.f/5 * t` and `res = (9.f/5 * t) + 32`
- You should check whether `scanf()`s are successful and the data read is valid in order not to invoke *undefined behavior* by using values of uninitialized variables having automatic-storage duration, which are indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, you use `printf` in the following way :

  ```
  printf("%.2f",&res);
  ```

  but according to what you want to print, you should change it to :

  ```
  printf("%.2f", res);
  ```
- Secondly, as you are reading a simple character, modify this line :

  ```
  scanf("%s",&c);
  ```

  to :

  ```
  scanf("%c", &c);
  ```
- Finally and most importantly, the statement :

  ```
  res = 4/5 * t;
  ```

  will compute the **integer quotient** (which will give `0` in case of `4/5`), but you want to do the float division. So you should change it to :

  ```
  res = (float)4/5 * t;
  ```

  or :

  ```
  res = 4/(float)5 * t;
  ```

  as one of the two members of the division needs to be `float` to get the result you want.

  Of course instead of casting you could also do :

  ```
  res = 4.0/5 * t;
  ```

  or :

  ```
  res = 4/5.0 * t;
  ```

  The same should also be applied to `9/5*t`, which should change to `9.0/5*t` or `9/5.0*t`.

Answer (score 2):

Of course,

```
printf("%.2f",res);  // without &
```

and

```
4.0/5   9.0/5  // .0 makes literal of double type
```

or better

```
4.0F/5   9.0F/5  // .0F makes literal of float type
```

in the expressions.

But my second advise is for the following code

```
scanf("%f",&t); 
getchar(); // cleaning the input stream from one `'\n'`
scanf("%s",&c);
```

It is better to write this part as

```
scanf("%f",&t);
while (getchar() != '\n'); // cleaning the input stream from everithing
c = getchar(); // reading one character
```

this approach allows to read correct character after input something like

> 1.34abdfsk
>
> R

In that case `abdfsk` as well as `\n` will be skipped by loop `while (getchar() != '\n');`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
scanf("%s",&c);
```

to

```
scanf("%c",&c); // %c format specifier for character
```

Change

```
printf("%.2f",&res);
```

to

```
printf("%.2f",res); // No address of operator required
```

In

```
res = 4/5 * t;
```

the `/` & `*` have the same precedence, hence the expression is evaluated left to right. So operator occurrence matters.

Since both 4 & 5 are evaluated as integers the division yields zero
and that is the reason you've got zero as the result. To force compiler to treat `4/5` as a float, you could explicitly mention at least one value as float:

```
res = 4/5.0F * t;
```

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't change anything